# Liferay not working on WebLogic Server

Tags: liferay, weblogic

Very general question here:

I have Liferay 6.1.1 ga2 set up on my Oracle WebLogic 12c.

It works fine on my local, but when I deploy it onto our development server, I lose all write permissions.

**E.g., changing the theme/color scheme, creating web content, pages, and saving changes to most things**

I try to import LARs however it is saying it is **not permitted**

I'm not seeing any errors in the logs, and the control panel messages are even telling me my content was created or change successfully (besides the LARs0, but everything stays the same.

Any reason(s) why my changes aren't showing up? I'll surely give a bounty if I can get pointed in the right direction here

Answer (score 0):

Given your description, I'd recommend checking OS issues, like write access to various folders, like temporary folders etc.. I guess that Liferay has proper permissions to the whole database (it's rare to have incomplete access) and can write to all tables. And you're operating on a portal-wide admin account, right?

Unrelated to LAR import, changes will not show up if you have workflow enabled - then you'd find the changes in the  list of tasks that need approval.

As staging has quite an obvious UI in 6.1, I assume you don't have staging activated, otherwise you just need to publish. In order to see new portlets, make sure that the "Edit Controls" checkbox in your dockbar is checked. This has bitten me more than once.

if you're running a cluster, make sure that you have set it up correctly, e.g. that you don't see cached content on your node.

Can you confirm that you can see the options to change on the UI, just that your changes aren't persisted?

Also, please note that Weblogic 12c is not on the "supported Appservers" list for Liferay 6.1, it's there for Liferay 6.2 only (probably due to release date). This doesn't mean that it shouldn't run, just that it's not tested for your version. Further, there's a GA3 release for 6.3 already, so you might want to check if it's a problem that's fixed in GA3.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into these issues and get back to you

Comment: Just to add, I can confirm that I see the options to change my UI, it is that my changes are indeed not persisted